# spl_autoload_register() function does not perform callback

Tags: php

Does anyone know why the spl_autoload_register() function is not executing the callback.
I've already tried using it in other ways, with an already created function instead of an anonymous function.
But I always have the same result, it doesn't perform the callback.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VEq2.png)

Comment: Does it register?
"Returns true on success or false on failure. "

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Are you doing something that should invoke this callback?

Comment: Giso Stallenberg - Return true